# jQuery remove element that contains another element with the class of ___

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I've looked for days and I cannot find a solution to this problem. It's probably VERY obvious, but is there a way to remove an element that contains another element with the class of something? In this case, I want to remove a `<p>` element that contains an anchor with the class of "tumblr_blog". I would use :contains, but the paragraph by default contains a colon which does not have a class, and the paragraph element does not have a class, so is there a way to remove a paragraph that contains an anchor with the class of tumblr_blog? This script should also remove the : in the paragraph even though it doesn't have a class. If anyone could help me it would really make my night. Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you Alex! One last thing, it works on the first page, but when new elements are loaded via the infinite-scroll function by Paul Irish, the code no longer works because a new page is loaded without refreshing. Here is my code, is there a way to implement the code on new elements that are loaded?

```
<script>
$(function(){
var $container = $('#posts');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.masonry({
itemSelector: '#entry',
columnWidth: 370,
});
});
$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector : '#page-nav', // selector for the paged navigation 
nextSelector : '#page-nav a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '#entry', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
loading: {
finishedMsg: '<em></em>',
}
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
// hide new items while they are loading
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
// show elems now they're ready
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
}
);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...is there a way to remove a paragraph that contains an anchor with the class of `tumblr_blog`?

You could use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$('p:has(a.tumblr_blog)').remove();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crFPn/).

For better performance, select all `p` and then use the `has()` method.

If you don't have jQuery, you could do it with...

```
var allP = document.querySelectorAll('p');

Array.forEach(allP, function(p) {
    if (p.querySelector('a.tumblr_blog').length) {
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
});
```

So it works with the [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) plugin, add this code to the callback when new content is loaded in as per the documentation.

Comment: Oh my god thank you SO much. I've been trying to figure this out for so long! Do you have a skype by any chance?

Comment: @JamesCharless I do, but for what reasons do you wish to contact me on it?

Comment: well I'm quite bad at jquery and javascript, but I always end up coding it a lot. I don't want to spam stack overflow with my silly questions that are considered ameture to other people, so I was wondering if I could ask you when I have javascript/jquery questions? You seem like a very smart and nice person. :-) Also, the script works, but only on the first page of my blog. When my blog loads the second page via infinite scrolling, the p elements are back. How can i make it so they are ALWAYS removed? http://-respawn.tumblr.com/

Comment: @JamesCharless I don't really offer unpaid help outside of here. You would need to call this code in the callback of your infinite scroll function.

Comment: Sigh.. I dislike when people charge for questions. But anyway, how would I do that? I know the code would go in this area, but where?:

function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
});
}
);
});

Comment: @alex, What's with `querySelector`? Don't we use `document.getElementsByTagName` now? http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementbyid/11

Comment: @JamesCharless What I mean is, I don't do outside work for free. You should edit your original question if you want to post more code.

Comment: @Walkerneo That performance test isn't too relevant to my example.

Comment: @JamesCharless // Sigh..there's no free lunch in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Just start by selecting the element with the specific class, then remove its parent.

```
<p>
 :
 <a class="tumblr_blog">...</a>
 ...
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p a.tumblr_blog').parent().remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work if the `a` isn't a direct descendent of the `p`. You could use `closest('p')`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do a 'normal' CSS selector and then use the `.parent()` method.

```
$("p a.tumblr_blog").parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll("*[class~='className']") will return a nodelist of all of the nodes with that class. Then loop through each one and use .parentNode to get a reference to its parent, which you can then remove it from its .parentNode using ref.parentNode.removeChild(ref); Put all together:

```
var nodesWithClass = document.querySelectorAll("*[class~='className']");
for (var i=0;i<nodesWithClass.length;i++)
{
    nodesWithClass[i].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(nodesWithClass[i].parentNode);
}
```

Comment: hah, missed the JQuery tag - JQuery makes it really easy, as other answers will show you.